# Vertically centre a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically centre the submenu on this page in between the two lines.

http://complete.sanscode.com/Landscape.

See the part that says Master Planning | Park... etc. I'd like to use jquery to centre that. Does anyone know how?

**Edit:** The menu can be more than one line.

Thanks

Jason

Comment: why do you need jQ to do this. Why not CSS `{text-align:center;}`

Comment: Sorry Guys. I want the vertical centre here, not the horizontal centre.

Comment: The menu can be more than 1 line so the line height can cause issues, hence jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the CSS `line-height` to a fixed value: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/yHJjx/

Comment: Setting the line-height equal to the height of the containing element will vertically center the text, however you should keep in mind that if the text overflows onto two lines (for example a user has text zoomed) your layout will break and half the text will be lost.

Comment: @Moses ... only if the container element has a height set. If you only set the line-height, then the container's height will be based on the line-height, and if the text overflows into a second line, the container will grow to wrap both lines.

Comment: @Šime Vidas, but your layout still breaks

Comment: @Šime My comment was related to Moses's comment - the line-height will cause a large gap between the two lines, rather than centering, if the text wraps onto two lines.

Comment: OMG that was so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you are wanting to center an element in a fixed height area? You are best off just adding a top margin to puch the nav down and adjust the height attribute accordingly..

Also, your nav leaves the screen when you shrink the browser window too. Id consider adding a container div with the fixed width you are after and margin auto to center. Slightly off topic but it should make you elements easier to manage.

Comment: A problem occurs when the menu is two lines long. Thanks for your other advice though, good point. +1

Answer (score 1):

Remove top padding from your `#navigation` id and add a `line-height:120px`. You don't need jQuery for this.

```
#navigation {
height:120px;
line-height:120px;
padding:0 1em 0 0;
width:720px;
}
```

Comment: Hey Mate, Problem is the menu can stretch onto two lines. Is there a way to account for this with line height?

Comment: @jason You shouldn't allow your menu to stretch to 2 lines. Not a good practice. If you need to have 2 line then you need to take a different approach laying out your template. For the purpose of this question will solve your problem.

Comment: lol, "not a good practice"... that's a bit random. Do you have some documentation to support that? +1 for the effort, but unfortunately I can't accept this as the answer because i've specifically asked for javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up and used tables.

http://giveupandusetables.com/

but the line height thing did the trick, see above answers

Answer (score 0):

You can set the css attribute 'line-height' to proper content to make it vertical center, just have a try