# Vertically centre child in floated parent

Tags: html, css, wordpress

**Question:**

Is it possible to vertically centre a child element in a floated *div* in relation to the dynamic height of a floated *div* along side it?

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pluQ.png)

**Background:**

I'm using a WordPress theme which has shortcodes for creating columns. The columns are created through floated divs. As such, I'd like to stick to using float, instead of using a table layout as has been suggested to similar questions ([Vertically center content of floating div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168145/vertically-center-content-of-floating-div)).

I'd like the result to be responsive. The image height changes with the screen width, and so I cannot set explicit height or margins on the *p* element.
The text in *p* is also more than one line, so I cannot set line-height as a solution ([Vertically centre a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175819/vertically-centre-a-div)).

**Example:**

http://codepen.io/besiix/pen/rxdOWM

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #50C5B7;
  padding: 5px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.one-half {
  float: left;
  width:48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.last {
  clear: right;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="one-half">
    <p class="v-center"> This wants to be centered vertically in relation to the image on the right.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="one-half last">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.premiercottages.co.uk/images/regions/Scotland.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flexbox, see jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d5Lptwut/2/

```
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="one-half vertical-align">
    <p> This wants to be centered vertically in relation to the image on the right.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="one-half last">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.premiercottages.co.uk/images/regions/Scotland.jpg">
  </div>
</section>

.wrapper {
    background-color: #50C5B7;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.one-half {
    width:48%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.vertical-align {
    flex-item-align: center;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
    align-self: center;

}
.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution, although this doesn't answer the question of whether this outcome is possible within floated element. Are there any particular benefits to using flexbox as apposed to inline-block?

Comment: I would say that in your situation there would be no real benefit to using flexbox as apposed to inline-block. As to wether this can be done with child elements of floated divs, the answer is yes you can, but you need to put the floating elements inside other elements... like such https://jsfiddle.net/d5Lptwut/7/ and in your case I'm not sure you want to change the HTML

Comment: That is absolutely perfect! I can wrap the shortcode entry in a wrapper div as shown in your jsfiddle, and the content is vertically aligned. This is exactly what I was after, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: #50C5B7;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.one-half {
    width:48%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.vertical-align {
    flex-item-align: center;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
    align-self: center;

}
.last {
    margin-right: 0;
clear:both;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/fnm81hrc/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: inline-block`, this allow `vertical-align`elements:

http://codepen.io/yukulele/pen/bEvYEZ?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks, elegant solution to the problem! But again, doesn't answer the question as to whether a solution to the problem can be found while still using float.

Comment: `float` is make to place an element (often an image) in a corner of a text block (like on newspaper article), i think it should never be used for other thinks.

Comment: Agreed, it has caused a few issues. I wonder why it's been used. As far as I've seen there is no solution while still using float. In which case, I'll re-write the shortcode for the theme. Thanks.